# Should i use MinGW for C++/CMake project to minimize dependencies of MS's DLLs?

Tags: c++, mingw

When i use Visual Studio, my executables depends on microsoft redistributable package - the package that deploys MS's runtime DLLs. That is annoying to me. What disatwantages my executable would have if i would use MinGW?

I also want to try link with lib- avcodec/avformat, that are built by MinGW and i have no my own mind power to build them in VS from src.

Answer (score 0):

In case of using MinGW you will depend on DLLs that are shipped with mingw. It is not big deal to change one vendor to another.

If you already have MS project, review possibility to statically link MS libraries (it is option is provided for some of VisualStudio projects on creation time in project options)

Comment: I also want to try link with lib- avcodec/avformat, that are built by MinGW and i have no mind power to build them from scratch from src.

Answer (score 0):

You can link everything statically with MinGW. Use the `-static` linker flag.

No need for redistributing any DLL's, but you have to make sure that in the c++, there's no exceptions being passed over DLL boundaries (so make sure every C++ library is linked statically in this case).